# Finding the domain of definition and the maximum interval of existence of an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

1. Consider the following one-dimensional system,
   dx/dt = F(x), where F : (0,∞) → R is given by,
   $$F(x) = 1\div2x$$ ∀x > 0. For p > 0, find the solution, u : J → R, of the above ODE, subject to
   the following initial condition:
   x(0) = p
2. Find the maximal interval of existence, J, for the solution, u, computed
   in part (a) of this problem. Compute,
   $$\ \lim_{t\to -(p^2)^+}u(t)$$
3. Let F be as in problem 1. Denote by θ(t, p) the solution u(t), ∀t ∈ J of the
   IVP given in problem 1. Find the domain of the definition of θ and verify that θ is continuous on
   its domain.

I solved the first problem and the result was $$u(t)=({\sqrt {(t+p^2})}$$
Now I am confused between the maximum interval of existence and the domain of definition. I know J is an interval and it must contain the initial time and domain contains both (t,p). $$θ:I×U  → U$$ U is an open subset of R and D⊆I×U and J⊆I containing t. Here's what I did $$J=(-p^2,\infty)$$ and $$\ \lim_{t\to -(p^2)^+}u(t)=0$$. And $$D=(0,\infty)$$ So am I correct? Also how should I show θ is continuous? Do I have to show that F(x) satisfies the Lipshcitz condition or can I use the limits to show it is continous. I also have to show θ is a C^1 flow map in its domain.

Comment: Huh?  The solution to $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac12x$ is not $x(t)=\sqrt{t+p^2}$.

Comment: Sorry it is $$1\div2x$$